# Lubuntu 16.04.3 LTS software centre not showing popular software

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, software-center

I have installed Lubuntu 16.04.3 LTS alongside Windows for testing.
Tried to install MariaDB through software centre.

[image]

As the screenshot explains, mariadb, (or many other popular s/w) are not listed.

What I tried on terminal---

:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure lubuntu-software-center

[image: response on terminal]

Still no good.
I think there is some prob with repositories (I am an amateur with linux).

Can anybody pl. suggest how to fix it?

[image: software and updates1]
[image: software and updates2]

Comment: Have you enabled the `Universe` repository?

Comment: You mean `sudo add-apt-repository universe`  command?

Comment: From memory, click on the main menu and then under Preferences, look for "Software Sources".

Comment: Checked as you mentioned. Screenshots are attached in OP by editing it. Pl. guide. Thanks.

Comment: `vin@vinlin:~$ sudo add-apt-repository universe

'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources`

Comment: Another surprising thing --- I did not find "software center" in synaptic package manager.  It has "software-properties-common" and "software-properties-gtk".  How do I add it there?